# Issues with eclim installation

Tags: java, eclipse, eclim

I've been having issues with my eclim install where in the GUI install, I am prompted for the directory of my Eclipse installation. When I input the directory I can't proceed, with the input bar turning red and the Next button made unavailable.

Here is copy of the post that I made to the eclim-users Google Groups page (which seems to be pretty unresponsive):

> I might be missing something trivial here, but I can't seem to figure
>   out what's wrong.
>
> I'm currently working on OS X (El Capitan), with MacVim (7.4).
>   Eclipse.app is installed to ~/Applications/java-mars, so I assumed
>   that was the directory that eclim is asking for in the GUI
>   installation; however, the directory bar turns red and denies me from
>   continuing.
>
> I then tried cloning from git and using ant to build eclim, using
>   -Declipse.home=~/Applications/java-mars/Eclipse.app/, but the build fails, saying org.eclipse.core.runtime doesn't exist. This seems to be
>   located in my ~/.p2 directory, but the build fails when I try with
>   that set in the Declipse.home flag.
>
> I must be overlooking something trivial, like specifying the wrong
>   directory, but any help pointing me to the right direction would be
>   appreciated.

I ended up getting eclim to compile from source, setting `Declipse.home` to one of the directories in my `~/.p2` where `org.eclipse.core.runtime` was located, but now I can't seem to execute `eclimd` with this as my logs:

```
!SESSION 2016-01-21 03:09:07.366 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_65
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  --launcher.suppressErrors -refresh -application org.eclim.application
Command-line arguments:  --launcher.suppressErrors -debug -clean -refresh -application org.eclim.application

!ENTRY org.eclim 4 0 2016-01-21 03:09:09.335
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclim [94]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.filebuffers

        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclim.core 4 0 2016-01-21 03:09:09.338
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclim.core [95]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclim
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclim; bundle-version="2.5.0"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclim [94]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.filebuffers

        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclim.jdt 4 0 2016-01-21 03:09:09.339
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclim.jdt [96]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.ant

        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclim.vimplugin 4 0 2016-01-21 03:09:09.339
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclim.vimplugin [97]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.ant

        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state.nl_ja 2 0 2016-01-21 03:09:12.315
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state.nl_ja [323]
  Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state
  Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state


!ENTRY org.eclim 2 0 2016-01-21 03:09:12.315
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclim [94]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.filebuffers


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state.nl_zh 2 0 2016-01-21 03:09:12.315
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state.nl_zh [324]
  Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state
  Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state


!ENTRY org.eclim.jdt 2 0 2016-01-21 03:09:12.316
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclim.jdt [96]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.ant


!ENTRY org.eclim.vimplugin 2 0 2016-01-21 03:09:12.316
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclim.vimplugin [97]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.ant


!ENTRY org.eclim.core 2 0 2016-01-21 03:09:12.316
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclim.core [95]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclim
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclim; bundle-version="2.5.0"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclim [94]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.filebuffers


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-01-21 03:09:12.316
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclim.application" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: com.jrockit.mc.rcp.application.app, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.GenTopic, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application, org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool.
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```